# Strawberry CPAN crash after Camelbox installation

Tags: perl, windows-7, crash, cpan

CPAN of my Strawberry perl installation used to work fine. A while ago I installed Camelbox perl to get its GTK libraries. I fixed the PATHs to leave no trace of Camelbox, and added its libs PERL5LIB. This solved my GTK-on-Windows-7 problems.

Today, I had to use CPAN again, but it crashes inexplicably. It is the Strawberry CPAN that runs.

```
C:\Users\tim>cpan -v
C:\strawberry\perl\bin/cpan script version 1.9, CPAN.pm version 1.9402
```

When I try to `get` anything -- including already installed modules -- CPAN successfully deletes a temporary directory, and suddenly crashes.

```
cpan> get List::Object
Running get for module 'List::Object'
Checksum for C:\strawberry\cpan\sources\authors\id\M\MS\MSHILTONJ\List-Object-0.01.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache C:\strawberry\cpan\build for sizes
............................................................................DONE

DEL(1/1): C:\strawberry\cpan\build\tmp-16240

C:\Users\tim>
```

I get a generic Windows *perl.exe has stopped working* popup.

I'm fairly sure that this is caused by Camelbox. What can I do to fix or debug this? I've found no CPAN debug switches.

As daxim suggested, I ran cpan in the perl debugger. Here is the output as [RAR (127 KB)](http://dump.gurka.se/cpan-dbg-1.rar) and [clear text (10.8 MB)](http://dump.gurka.se/cpan-dbg-1.txt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I fixed the PATHs to leave no trace of Camelbox, and added its libs PERL5LIB [to a Strawberry installation]

Your self-caused problem is on the C/object linking level. Mixing XS libraries for different versions of Perl is a bad idea.

Run the CPAN client under the Perl debugger, enable `t`race, `c`ontinue until the crash happens. The Perl library that was loaded last hints you at the faulty link library. My gut suspects readline.

---

Crash occurs at Compress/Raw/Bzip2.pm line 63 which is `XSLoader::load('Compress::Raw::Bzip2', $XS_VERSION);`. This attempts to load the XS Bzip2 DLL whose exact name eludes me because I don't have a Strawberry installation around for checking. Reinstall this library without invoking the CPAN client, or try to hunt down all the pieces and delete them.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I forgot to mention that the crash happens even if I remove Camelbox from PERL5LIB, so Strawberry shouldn't know about it at all.

Comment: I've added the trace output to my question. ReadLine does not seem to be related, but I can't figure out what is.

Comment: For reference: I ended up using only the (outdated) Camelbox.